# В чем отличия отзывчивой от адаптивной верстки?

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript, css

Я верстаю резиновые макеты, использую `@media(max-width: ***px) {}` и называю это адаптивной версткой. Прав ли я и каковы отличия между отзывчивой и адаптивной версткой, если это не одно и тоже? Хотя читал что есть отличия, но все так расписано, что ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный вопрос на мой взгляд неплохо освещен в статье: [Адаптивный веб-дизайн vs. Отзывчивый веб-дизайн, в чем разница?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148224/) на хабре. В конце статьи есть два предложения, которые описывают всю суть:

> Отзывчивый веб-дизайн является частью адаптивного. Отзывчивый веб-дизайн = «резиновый» макет, в то время как адаптивный веб-дизайн = «резиновый» макет + прогрессивное улучшение.

Comment: Т.е. отзывчивый - это те самые простые резиновые макеты. Табличную верстку прошлых годов тоже можно назвать отзывчивой?

Comment: да, в случае с отзывчивым речь идет лишь о резиновых макетах. с табличной версткой думаю стоит осторожнее, отчасти да, но тем не менее подход несколько другой, и значительно менее гибкий.

Comment: Резиновый дизайн не означает отзывчивый. И табличная верстка уж точно не отзывчивая. В отзывчивой верстке у вас может меняться лейаут (из трехколоночного в одноколоночный или двухколоночный - в зависимости от ширины экрана), а в резиновой верстке просто растягиваются колонки и зачастую с соххранением общего лейаута.

Comment: @iKuzko, хорошо, тогда если это отзывчивый, то что такое адаптивный. До вашего комментария я был уверен, что это адаптивный)

Comment: адаптивный дизайн это далеко не только верстка. суть в том, чтобы предоставить пользователю наиболее удобный и функциональный интерфейс на любом устройстве, не смотря на ограничения такового (размер экрана, другой метод ввода)

Comment: @павел-азанов то бишь, например, убирая некоторые элементы сайта?

Comment: @inferus-vv: да, или заменяя их другими. например вместо таблицы пользователь увидит на своем смартфоне диаграмму. конечное назначение остается прежним, сайт не теряет функциональности, но интерфейс "адаптируется" под девайс пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

[Адаптивный веб-дизайн](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)

Прочитайте разделы: Понятия, Основные принципы.